# The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure

Tags: python, authentication, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

Hi I'm trying to call a graph through python but I get this error

> author: The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure.

This is my code:

```py
import csv
from py2neo import Graph, Node

N_MOVIES = 1000
N_RATINGS = 1000
N_TAGS = 1000
N_LINKS = 1000
USERNAME = "arooj"
PASS = "abcd" #default

graph = Graph("bolt://localhost:7687", auth = (USERNAME, PASS))

def main():
    createGenreNodes()

    print("Step 1 out of 4: loading movie nodes")
    loadMovies()

    print("Step 2 out of 4: loading rating relationships")
    loadRatings()

    print("Step 3 out of 4: loading tag relationships")
    loadTags()

    print("Step 4 out of 4: updating links to movie nodes")
    loadLinks()
```

Comment: You need to show a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: i updated with a snip of a code

Comment: Can you put up the code where you are creating the Neo4j connection?

Comment: i think now its clear just have a look

Answer (score 0):

The first time you login, we have to set the password.

Execute the following:

1. docker exec -it name_of_docker bash
2. cypher-shell -u neo4j -p neo4

This will ask for the new password. Once the password is changed, pass the new password in your code.

Comment: hi pallavi thanks for the reply where do i have to execute the following statements u mentioned?